# Throw an exception from inside javascript

Tags: javascript, java, activiti, nashorn

I have a project that uses Activiti engine.
It support running scripts using Nashorn. 
I have no problem running this code in either script tasks or in task listeners.
But when using execution listeners I have issues.

In my script I want to throw an error that should be caught by the java code.
For example:

```
    throw new Error("this is an error");
```

But I get an error:

```
    problem evaluating script: Error: this is an error in scripts/error.js at line number 8 at column number 1
```

I have also tried this initially:

```
    var BpmnError = Java.type(org.activiti.engine.delegate.BpmnError');
    throw new BpmnError("BusinessExeptionOccured","a Message");
```

In this case no error is caught as if the throw never happened.

In the Activiti documentation it states:

```
  As of Activiti 5.9, it is possible to throw BPMN Errors from user code inside Service Tasks or Script Tasks. In order to do this, a special ActivitiException called BpmnError can be thrown in JavaDelegates or scripts
```

I have not been able find any example of how this can be done.

I have also not seen any examples of JavaScript code that can throw a jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException
A comment in the opendJDK ECMAException states:

```
Exception used to implement ECMAScript "throw" from scripts.
```

Any help with this will be appreciated.

Comment: I have updated the question and removed the comment.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion from Lian (that he also added in comments, making it hard to find)? `try { // eval something } catch(ScriptException sx) { sx.printStackTrace(); } } `

Answer (score 2):

You can catch the ScriptException and then access the thrown ECMAScript object from there.

Sample code:

```
import javax.script.*;
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ScriptEngineManager m = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine e = m.getEngineByName("nashorn");
        try {
            e.eval("throw new Error('this is an error');");
        } catch (ScriptException se) {
            // get the original cause
            Throwable cause = se.getCause();
            // in this case, the cause is a nashorn exception
            if (cause instanceof NashornException) {
                NashornException ne = (NashornException)cause;
                // Access the underlying ECMAScript error object thrown
                Object obj = ne.getEcmaError();
                // print ECMA object 'as is'
                System.out.println(obj);

                // In this example, the thrown ECMAScript object is
                // an instanceof Error. Script objects are accessible
                // as JSObject in java code.
                if (obj instanceof JSObject) {
                    JSObject jsObj = (JSObject)obj;
                    System.out.println(jsObj.getMember("message"));
                    System.out.println(jsObj.getMember("name"));
                    // access nashorn specific 'stack' property
                    System.out.println("stack trace: " + jsObj.getMember("stack"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe that the problem is in nashorn and I have no java code.
This question is specific to Activiti BMPN engine.

Answer (score 0):

In Activiti Script Task you can use the following:

```
throw ("Message")
```

I hope this help you

Comment: Script tasks and task listeners work fine. No problem there.
It is specifically execution listeners that have this problem.

Answer (score -1):

throw "this is an error";

See here for an explanation: [JavaScript error handling](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp). Since Nashorn  implements ECMAScript 5.1 (as is claimed here [OpenJDK Wiki, Nashorn extensions](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions)) the normal JavaScript error handling should work.

Comment: The OP is asking  "*I want to throw an error that should be caught by the Java code*"

Comment: You can already catch this:         try { // eval something
        } catch(ScriptException sx) {
         sx.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
the result is:  script error: javax.script.ScriptException: column <X> not found in <eval> at line number 9 at column number 2
 at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:467)
 at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:451)

Comment: Fix your answer  instead of using a comment. It's not very readable in a comment, comments are not for you to write an answer.